# Changing dataframes in bulk? How to apply a list of operations to multiple dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, reshape2

So, I have 6 data frames, all look like this (with different values):
[image]

Now I want to create a new column in all the data frames for the country. Then I want to convert it into a long df. This is how I am going about it.

```
dlist<- list(child_mortality,fertility,income_capita,life_expectancy,population)

convertlong <- function(trial){
  trial$country <- rownames(trial)
  trial <- melt(trial)
  colnames(trial)<- c("country","year",trial)
}

for(i in dlist){
 convertlong(i)
}
```

After running this I get:

```
Using country as id variables
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

That's all, it doesn't do the operations on the data frames. I am pretty sure I'm taking a stupid mistake, but I looked online on forums and cannot figure it out.

Comment: In the colnames() function, I didn't put trial in quotes, because I want the name of the third column to be the name of the dataframe. Is that the way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can replace

```
trial$country <- rownames(trial)
```

by

```
trial <- cbind(trial, rownames(trial))
```

Comment: and for your question about colnames(), you can do colnames(trial)<- c("country","year",deparse(substitute(trial)))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` attempt -

```
library(tidyverse)

#Put the dataframes in a named list. 
dlist<- dplyr::lst(child_mortality, fertility, 
                   income_capita, life_expectancy,population)
#lst is not a typo!!

#Write a function which creates a new column with rowname
#and get's the data in long format
#The column name for 3rd column is passed separately (`col`).
convertlong <- function(trial, col){
  trial %>%
    rownames_to_column('country') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -country, names_to = 'year', values_to = col)
}

#Use `imap` to pass dataframe as well as it's name to the function. 
dlist <- imap(dlist, convertlong)

#If you want the changes to be reflected for dataframes in global environment.
list2env(dlist, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works great! I have a few questions. in pivot_longer, when you pass col to values_to, how does it know to name the column with the data frame name? Also, is there any significance to the minus sign in -country?

Comment: 1. `imap` passes two arguments to function `convertlong`. First one is the dataframe and second one is it's name so `col` becomes the name in the function. 2. Yes, significance of `-` sign is that it gets the data in long format for all the columns except `country`. `-` in a way suggests to exclude that column.